# I am creating a website with MCQ. How I can show the number of correct answers a person selected?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a website with MCQ. which, when the user selects an option it automatically shows the correct and incorrect answer at the moment of selection. Now I would like to show the 'number of correct answers' the user selected at the end. How to do that, please help me. code is below with three questions

```
<h3>1. how many charecters in the word "lion" </h3>
<p>Choose 1 answer</p>
<hr/>
<div id='block-11' style='padding: 10px;'>
  <label for='option-11' style=' padding: 5px; font-size: 1.0rem;'>
    <input type='radio' name='option'  id='option-11' onclick='displayAnswer1()' style='transform: scale(1.6); margin-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle; margin-top: -2px;' />
    A)  4</label>
  <span id='result-11'></span>
</div>
<hr />

<div id='block-12' style='padding: 10px;'>
  <label for='option-12' style=' padding: 5px; font-size: 1.0rem;'>
    <input type='radio' name='option'  id='option-12' onclick='displayAnswer1()' style='transform: scale(1.6); margin-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle; margin-top: -2px;' />
    B) 3</label>
  <span id='result-12'></span>
</div>
<hr />

<div id='block-13' style='padding: 10px;'>
  <label for='option-13' style=' padding: 5px; font-size: 1.0rem;'>
    <input type='radio' name='option'  id='option-13' onclick='displayAnswer1()' style='transform: scale(1.6); margin-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle; margin-top: -2px;' />
   C) 1</label>
  <span id='result-13'></span>
</div>
<hr />

<div id='block-14' style='padding: 10px;'>
  <label for='option-14' style=' padding: 5px; font-size: 1.0rem;'>
    <input type='radio' name='option'  id='option-14' onclick='displayAnswer1()' style='transform: scale(1.6); margin-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle; margin-top: -2px;' />
    D) 2</label>
  <span id='result-14'></span>
</div>
<hr />
<script type="text/javascript">

  function displayAnswer1() {
  if (document.getElementById('option-11').checked) {
    displayAnswer11()
  }
  if (document.getElementById('option-12').checked) {
    document.getElementById('block-12').style.border = '3px solid red'
    document.getElementById('result-12').style.color = 'red'
    document.getElementById('result-12').innerHTML = 'Incorrect!'
    displayAnswer11()
  }
  if (document.getElementById('option-13').checked) {
    document.getElementById('block-13').style.border = '3px solid red'
    document.getElementById('result-13').style.color = 'red'
    document.getElementById('result-13').innerHTML = 'Incorrect!'
    displayAnswer11()
  }
  if (document.getElementById('option-14').checked) {
    document.getElementById('block-14').style.border = '3px solid red'
    document.getElementById('result-14').style.color = 'red'
    document.getElementById('result-14').innerHTML = 'Incorrect!'
    displayAnswer11()
  }
}


function displayAnswer11() {
    document.getElementById('block-11').style.border = '3px solid limegreen'
    document.getElementById('result-11').style.color = 'limegreen'
    document.getElementById('result-11').innerHTML = 'Correct!'
  }


  
</script>
<br><br>

<div style=' position: relative; '>
<h3>2. how many letter inthe word "me"</h3>
<p>Choose 1 answer</p>
<hr />

<div id='block-21' style='padding: 10px;'>
  <label for='option-21' style=' padding: 5px; font-size: 1.0rem;'>
    <input type='radio' name='option'  id='option-21' onclick='displayAnswer2()'  style='transform: scale(1.6); margin-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle; margin-top: -2px;' />
    A) 1</label>
  <span id='result-21'></span>
</div>
<hr />

<div id='block-22' style='padding: 10px;'>
  <label for='option-22' style=' padding: 5px; font-size: 1.0rem;'>
    <input type='radio' name='option'  id='option-22' onclick='displayAnswer2()' style='transform: scale(1.6); margin-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle; margin-top: -2px;' />
    B) 2</label>
  <span id='result-22'></span>
</div>
<hr />

<div id='block-23' style='padding: 10px;'>
  <label for='option-23' style=' padding: 5px; font-size: 1.0rem;'>
    <input type='radio' name='option'  id='option-23' onclick='displayAnswer2()' style='transform: scale(1.6); margin-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle; margin-top: -2px;' />
    C) 3</label>
  <span id='result-23'></span>
</div>
<hr />

<div id='block-24' style='padding: 10px;'>
  <label for='option-24' style=' padding: 5px; font-size: 1.0rem;'>
    <input type='radio' name='option'  id='option-24' onclick='displayAnswer2()' style='transform: scale(1.6); margin-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle; margin-top: -2px;' />
    D) 4</label>
  <span id='result-24'></span>
</div>
<hr />
</div>
<script>
//    The function evaluates the answer and displays result
function displayAnswer2() {
  
  if (document.getElementById('option-21').checked) {
    document.getElementById('block-21').style.border = '3px solid red'
    document.getElementById('result-21').style.color = 'red'
    document.getElementById('result-21').innerHTML = 'Incorrect!'
    displayAnswer22()
  }
  if (document.getElementById('option-22').checked) {
    displayAnswer22()
  }
  if (document.getElementById('option-23').checked) {
    document.getElementById('block-23').style.border = '3px solid red'
    document.getElementById('result-23').style.color = 'red'
    document.getElementById('result-23').innerHTML = 'Incorrect!'
    displayAnswer22()
  }
  if (document.getElementById('option-24').checked) {
    document.getElementById('block-24').style.border = '3px solid red'
    document.getElementById('result-24').style.color = 'red'
    document.getElementById('result-24').innerHTML = 'Incorrect!'
    displayAnswer22()
  }
}
function displayAnswer22() {
    document.getElementById('block-22').style.border = '3px solid limegreen'
    document.getElementById('result-22').style.color = 'limegreen'
    document.getElementById('result-22').innerHTML = 'Correct!'
  }


</script>



<br><br>


<div style=' position: relative; '>
<h3>3. which is actually a name </h3>
<p>Choose 1 answer</p>
<hr />

<div id='block-31' style='padding: 5px;'>
  <label for='option-31' style=' padding: 5px; font-size: 1.0rem;'>
    <input type='radio' name='option'  id='option-31' onclick='displayAnswer3()' style='transform: scale(1.6); margin-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle; margin-top: -2px;' />
    A) 3nh r</label>
  <span id='result-31'></span>
</div>
<hr />

<div id='block-32' style='padding: 5px;'>
  <label for='option-32' style=' padding: 5px; font-size: 1.0rem;'>
    <input type='radio' name='option'  id='option-32' onclick='displayAnswer3()' style='transform: scale(1.6); margin-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle; margin-top: -2px;' />
    B) jack</label>
  <span id='result-32'></span>
</div>
<hr />

<div id='block-33' style='padding: 5px;'>
  <label for='option-33' style=' padding: 5px; font-size: 1.0rem;'>
    <input type='radio' name='option'  id='option-33' onclick='displayAnswer3()' style='transform: scale(1.6); margin-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle; margin-top: -2px;' />
    C) kdikduf</label>
  <span id='result-33'></span>
</div>
<hr />

<div id='block-34' style='padding: 5px;'>
  <label for='option-34' style=' padding: 5px; font-size: 1.0rem;'>
    <input type='radio' name='option' value='1/6' id='option-34' onclick='displayAnswer3()' style='transform: scale(1.6); margin-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle; margin-top: -2px;' />
    D) lkjhh</label>
  <span id='result-34'></span>
</div>
<hr />
</div>
<script>
//    The function evaluates the answer and displays result
function displayAnswer3() {
  
  if (document.getElementById('option-31').checked) {
    document.getElementById('block-31').style.border = '3px solid red'
    document.getElementById('result-31').style.color = 'red'
    document.getElementById('result-31').innerHTML = 'Incorrect!'
    displayAnswer33()
  }
  if (document.getElementById('option-32').checked) {
    displayAnswer33()
  }
  if (document.getElementById('option-33').checked) {
    document.getElementById('block-33').style.border = '3px solid red'
    document.getElementById('result-33').style.color = 'red'
    document.getElementById('result-33').innerHTML = 'Incorrect!'
    displayAnswer33()
  }
  if (document.getElementById('option-34').checked) {
    document.getElementById('block-34').style.border = '3px solid red'
    document.getElementById('result-34').style.color = 'red'
    document.getElementById('result-34').innerHTML = 'Incorrect!'
    displayAnswer33()
  }
}

function displayAnswer33() {
    document.getElementById('block-32').style.border = '3px solid limegreen'
    document.getElementById('result-32').style.color = 'limegreen'
    document.getElementById('result-32').innerHTML = 'Correct!'
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your solution, try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">    
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
  </head>
  <body>
      <h3>1. how many charecters in the word "lion" </h3>
  <p>Choose 1 answer</p>
  <hr/>
  <div id='block-11' style='padding: 10px;'>
    <label for='option-11' style=' padding: 5px; font-size: 1.0rem;'>
      <input type='radio' name='option'  id='option-11' onclick='displayAnswer1()' style='transform: scale(1.6); margin-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle; margin-top: -2px;' />
      A)  4</label>
    <span id='result-11'></span>
  </div>
  <hr />
  
  <div id='block-12' style='padding: 10px;'>
    <label for='option-12' style=' padding: 5px; font-size: 1.0rem;'>
      <input type='radio' name='option'  id='option-12' onclick='displayAnswer1()' style='transform: scale(1.6); margin-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle; margin-top: -2px;' />
      B) 3</label>
    <span id='result-12'></span>
  </div>
  <hr />
  
  <div id='block-13' style='padding: 10px;'>
    <label for='option-13' style=' padding: 5px; font-size: 1.0rem;'>
      <input type='radio' name='option'  id='option-13' onclick='displayAnswer1()' style='transform: scale(1.6); margin-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle; margin-top: -2px;' />
     C) 1</label>
    <span id='result-13'></span>
  </div>
  <hr />
  
  <div id='block-14' style='padding: 10px;'>
    <label for='option-14' style=' padding: 5px; font-size: 1.0rem;'>
      <input type='radio' name='option'  id='option-14' onclick='displayAnswer1()' style='transform: scale(1.6); margin-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle; margin-top: -2px;' />
      D) 2</label>
    <span id='result-14'></span>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var correct_answers = 0;
    function displayAnswer1() {
    if (document.getElementById('option-11').checked) {
      displayAnswer11()
    }
    if (document.getElementById('option-12').checked) {
      document.getElementById('block-12').style.border = '3px solid red'
      document.getElementById('result-12').style.color = 'red'
      document.getElementById('result-12').innerHTML = 'Incorrect!'
    }
    if (document.getElementById('option-13').checked) {
      document.getElementById('block-13').style.border = '3px solid red'
      document.getElementById('result-13').style.color = 'red'
      document.getElementById('result-13').innerHTML = 'Incorrect!'
    }
    if (document.getElementById('option-14').checked) {
      document.getElementById('block-14').style.border = '3px solid red'
      document.getElementById('result-14').style.color = 'red'
      document.getElementById('result-14').innerHTML = 'Incorrect!'
    }
  }
  
  
  function displayAnswer11() {
      document.getElementById('block-11').style.border = '3px solid limegreen'
      document.getElementById('result-11').style.color = 'limegreen'
      document.getElementById('result-11').innerHTML = 'Correct!'
      document.getElementById('correct_answers').innerHTML = "";
      document.getElementById('correct_answers').innerHTML = correct_answers+=1;
    }
  
  
    
  </script>
  <br><br>
  
  <div style=' position: relative; '>
  <h3>2. how many letter inthe word "me"</h3>
  <p>Choose 1 answer</p>
  <hr />
  
  <div id='block-21' style='padding: 10px;'>
    <label for='option-21' style=' padding: 5px; font-size: 1.0rem;'>
      <input type='radio' name='option'  id='option-21' onclick='displayAnswer2()'  style='transform: scale(1.6); margin-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle; margin-top: -2px;' />
      A) 1</label>
    <span id='result-21'></span>
  </div>
  <hr />
  
  <div id='block-22' style='padding: 10px;'>
    <label for='option-22' style=' padding: 5px; font-size: 1.0rem;'>
      <input type='radio' name='option'  id='option-22' onclick='displayAnswer2()' style='transform: scale(1.6); margin-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle; margin-top: -2px;' />
      B) 2</label>
    <span id='result-22'></span>
  </div>
  <hr />
  
  <div id='block-23' style='padding: 10px;'>
    <label for='option-23' style=' padding: 5px; font-size: 1.0rem;'>
      <input type='radio' name='option'  id='option-23' onclick='displayAnswer2()' style='transform: scale(1.6); margin-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle; margin-top: -2px;' />
      C) 3</label>
    <span id='result-23'></span>
  </div>
  <hr />
  
  <div id='block-24' style='padding: 10px;'>
    <label for='option-24' style=' padding: 5px; font-size: 1.0rem;'>
      <input type='radio' name='option'  id='option-24' onclick='displayAnswer2()' style='transform: scale(1.6); margin-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle; margin-top: -2px;' />
      D) 4</label>
    <span id='result-24'></span>
  </div>
  <hr />
  </div>
  <script>
  //    The function evaluates the answer and displays result
  function displayAnswer2() {
    
    if (document.getElementById('option-21').checked) {
      document.getElementById('block-21').style.border = '3px solid red'
      document.getElementById('result-21').style.color = 'red'
      document.getElementById('result-21').innerHTML = 'Incorrect!'
    }
    if (document.getElementById('option-22').checked) {
      displayAnswer22()
    }
    if (document.getElementById('option-23').checked) {
      document.getElementById('block-23').style.border = '3px solid red'
      document.getElementById('result-23').style.color = 'red'
      document.getElementById('result-23').innerHTML = 'Incorrect!'
    }
    if (document.getElementById('option-24').checked) {
      document.getElementById('block-24').style.border = '3px solid red'
      document.getElementById('result-24').style.color = 'red'
      document.getElementById('result-24').innerHTML = 'Incorrect!'
    }
  }
  function displayAnswer22() {
      document.getElementById('block-22').style.border = '3px solid limegreen'
      document.getElementById('result-22').style.color = 'limegreen'
      document.getElementById('result-22').innerHTML = 'Correct!'
      document.getElementById('correct_answers').innerHTML = "";
      document.getElementById('correct_answers').innerHTML += correct_answers+=1;
    }
  
  
  </script>
  
  
  
  <br><br>
  
  
  <div style=' position: relative; '>
  <h3>3. which is actually a name </h3>
  <p>Choose 1 answer</p>
  <hr />
  
  <div id='block-31' style='padding: 5px;'>
    <label for='option-31' style=' padding: 5px; font-size: 1.0rem;'>
      <input type='radio' name='option'  id='option-31' onclick='displayAnswer3()' style='transform: scale(1.6); margin-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle; margin-top: -2px;' />
      A) 3nh r</label>
    <span id='result-31'></span>
  </div>
  <hr />
  
  <div id='block-32' style='padding: 5px;'>
    <label for='option-32' style=' padding: 5px; font-size: 1.0rem;'>
      <input type='radio' name='option'  id='option-32' onclick='displayAnswer3()' style='transform: scale(1.6); margin-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle; margin-top: -2px;' />
      B) jack</label>
    <span id='result-32'></span>
  </div>
  <hr />
  
  <div id='block-33' style='padding: 5px;'>
    <label for='option-33' style=' padding: 5px; font-size: 1.0rem;'>
      <input type='radio' name='option'  id='option-33' onclick='displayAnswer3()' style='transform: scale(1.6); margin-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle; margin-top: -2px;' />
      C) kdikduf</label>
    <span id='result-33'></span>
  </div>
  <hr />
  
  <div id='block-34' style='padding: 5px;'>
    <label for='option-34' style=' padding: 5px; font-size: 1.0rem;'>
      <input type='radio' name='option' value='1/6' id='option-34' onclick='displayAnswer3()' style='transform: scale(1.6); margin-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle; margin-top: -2px;' />
      D) lkjhh</label>
    <span id='result-34'></span>
  </div>
  <hr />
  </div>
  <script>
  //    The function evaluates the answer and displays result
  function displayAnswer3() {
    
    if (document.getElementById('option-31').checked) {
      document.getElementById('block-31').style.border = '3px solid red'
      document.getElementById('result-31').style.color = 'red'
      document.getElementById('result-31').innerHTML = 'Incorrect!'
    }
    if (document.getElementById('option-32').checked) {
      displayAnswer33()
    }
    if (document.getElementById('option-33').checked) {
      document.getElementById('block-33').style.border = '3px solid red'
      document.getElementById('result-33').style.color = 'red'
      document.getElementById('result-33').innerHTML = 'Incorrect!'
    }
    if (document.getElementById('option-34').checked) {
      document.getElementById('block-34').style.border = '3px solid red'
      document.getElementById('result-34').style.color = 'red'
      document.getElementById('result-34').innerHTML = 'Incorrect!'
    }
  }
  
  function displayAnswer33() {
      document.getElementById('block-32').style.border = '3px solid limegreen'
      document.getElementById('result-32').style.color = 'limegreen'
      document.getElementById('result-32').innerHTML = 'Correct!'
      document.getElementById('correct_answers').innerHTML = "";
      document.getElementById('correct_answers').innerHTML += correct_answers+=1;
    }
  </script>
  <p id="correct_answers"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. But when the user selects an option, I want to shows the correct and incorrect answer at the moment of selection. And also there is no second chance is given to the user for selecting the option which already showed the correct answer. (In such case the user can select the correct answer showed and it will be also counted as the correct answer  ). please provide a solution for this also. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i will, just ask a separate question please. Please give me approve on answer if it helped you. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: It is good to say please, but you have to recognise that he did answer your original question. If you don't give him an Accept for the answer, why would he (or anyone else) invest again in answering another question? So far you are signalling the opposite...

Comment: @Eureka sorry , I am new here . Now I understand and I gived accept and up votes to the answer.

Comment: @FayisTp - great! We were all new once! Welcome and I hope you will continue to ask questions and in due course provide answers. 8-)

Answer (score 0):

I picked only the first question and made some adjustment to your markup to ease the process.

- I added a class of `block` to each `div` that holds a `label` and
  `input` tag
- I also added a class of `result` to each `span` tag that holds the
  result output.
- And finally, i added a parameter to the `displayAnswer1()` function
  called using the `onclick` attribute. This makes it easier to use for any question and not just the first question. You can specify the id of the correct answer in the function and it does the rest

This modifications are to ease the process in the javascript.

See code below with comments.

```js
function displayAnswer1(correctOptId){
    // get all option blocks in the document
    var blocks = document.querySelectorAll(".block");
    
    // run through each block
    blocks.forEach(function(currBlock){
        // get the radio input in the current block
        var option = currBlock.querySelector("input[name=option]");
        // get the result span element in the current block
        var result = currBlock.querySelector("span.result");
        
        // check if the id of the current option is the same as
        // that of the accepted option, if yes style as correct
        if(option.id == correctOptId){
            currBlock.style.border = '3px solid limegreen';
            result.style.color = 'limegreen';
            result.innerHTML = "Correct";
        }
        else{
            // style the other options as wrong
            currBlock.style.border = '3px solid red';
            result.style.color = 'red';
            result.innerHTML = "Incorrect";
        }
    })
};
```

```html
<h3>1. how many charecters in the word "lion" </h3>
<p>Choose 1 answer</p>
<hr />
<div class="block" id='block-11' style='padding: 10px;'>
  <label for='option-11' style=' padding: 5px; font-size: 1.0rem;'>
        <input type='radio' name='option' id='option-11' onclick='displayAnswer1("option-11")' style='transform: scale(1.6); margin-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle; margin-top: -2px;' />
        A) 4</label>
  <span class="result" id='result-11'></span>
</div>
<hr />

<div class="block" id='block-12' style='padding: 10px;'>
  <label for='option-12' style=' padding: 5px; font-size: 1.0rem;'>
        <input type='radio' name='option' id='option-12' onclick='displayAnswer1("option-11")' style='transform: scale(1.6); margin-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle; margin-top: -2px;' />
        B) 3</label>
  <span class="result" id='result-12'></span>
</div>
<hr />

<div class="block" id='block-13' style='padding: 10px;'>
  <label for='option-13' style=' padding: 5px; font-size: 1.0rem;'>
        <input type='radio' name='option' id='option-13' onclick='displayAnswer1("option-11")' style='transform: scale(1.6); margin-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle; margin-top: -2px;' />
        C) 1</label>
  <span class="result" id='result-13'></span>
</div>
<hr />

<div class="block" id='block-14' style='padding: 10px;'>
  <label for='option-14' style=' padding: 5px; font-size: 1.0rem;'>
        <input type='radio' name='option' id='option-14' onclick='displayAnswer1("option-11")' style='transform: scale(1.6); margin-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle; margin-top: -2px;' />
        D) 2</label>
  <span class="result" id='result-14'></span>
</div>
```